# Very new to Rails and following the Getting Started tutorial (creating a Blog) destroy method is giving me an error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have read through so many SO posts and Team Tree House posts regarding this issue but haven't been able to fix it.

When I click 'Delete' it tells me 'The action 'show' could not be found for TodoItemsController'

According to some responses I have tried the following:

*Make sure gem 'jquery-rails' is in gemfile and jquery_ujs is included in app/assets/javascripts/application.js file*

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

*Make sure that your  section in the layout includes the following:*

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

Here is my destroy method in todo_items_controller.rb

```
def destroy
  @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.find(params[:id])  
  if @todo_item.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Todo List item was deleted."
  else
    flash[:error] = "Todo List item could not be deleted."
  end
  redirect_to @todo_list
end
```

Here is my 'Delete' link in _todo_item.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', todo_list_todo_item_path(@todo_list, todo_item.id), 
method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

Here is my show.html.erb file in todo_lists

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @todo_list.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @todo_list.description %>
</p>

<div id="todo_items_wrapper">
  <%= render @todo_list.todo_items %>
  <div id="form">
    <%= render "todo_items/form" %>
  </div>
</div>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_todo_list_path(@todo_list) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', todo_lists_path %>
```

Here is my routes.rb file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :todo_lists do
    resources :todo_items
  end
  root "todo_lists#index"
end
```

I'm not sure what else to include. Any help is appreciated as this is my first attempt at creating a rails app.

Thanks

As requested here is my complete Controller file:

```
    class TodoItemsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_todo_list

    def create
      @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.create(todo_item_params)
      redirect_to @todo_list
    end

    def destroy
      @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.find(params[:id])  
      if @todo_item.destroy
        flash[:success] = "Todo List item was deleted."
      else
        flash[:error] = "Todo List item could not be deleted."
      end
      redirect_to @todo_list
    end

    private

    def set_todo_list
        @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:todo_list_id])
    end

    def todo_item_params
        params[:todo_item].permit(:content)
    end
end
```

As requested here is my error message once I add the following code to controller above private:

```
   def show
    @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:todo_list_id])
   end
```

Error message:

```
Missing template todo_items/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], 
:formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, 
:coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * 
"C:/Users/david/OneDrive/Documents/Ruby/todo/todo/app/views"


Posting error response when trying to delete when `show` method is included 
in controller:

Template is missing
Missing template todo_items/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], 
:formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, 
:coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * 
"C:/Users/david/OneDrive/Documents/Ruby/todo/todo/app/views"

Rails.root: C:/Users/david/OneDrive/Documents/Ruby/todo/todo

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
actionview (4.2.8) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:46:in `find'
actionview (4.2.8) lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:121:in `find'
C:in `find_template'
actionview (4.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:40:in `determine_template'
actionview (4.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:8:in `render'
actionview (4.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:46:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:27:in `render'
actionview (4.2.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.2.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.2.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.8) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.8) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
Request

Parameters:

{"todo_list_id"=>"1",
 "id"=>"1"}
```

Comment: Please show your complete controller, you must have a `show` action and `show.html.erb` for `redirect_to @todo_list` to work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Gerry I've add the complete controller. I tried adding a method 'show' but that gave me a missing template error.

Comment: I just checked the Getting started tutorial and it's more about messages and comments. Not really todolists. Anyway you should have a show action in your TodoListcontroller because you have already a show view : show.html.erb.. Have you not skipped a step ?

Comment: Could you add the complete log/error? Confirm that `show` action in in place before getting the error.

Comment: Your `link_to` is fine. I suspect `jquery` wasn't installed properly in your app.

Comment: @Maxence my apologies it's the creating a Todo tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fd1Vn-Wvy2w&list=PL23ZvcdS3XPLNdRYB_QyomQsShx59tpc-&index=6

Comment: @Pavan I don't suspect it's jquery only as I re-installed the gem and ensured it was in gemfile correctly.

Comment: @haletothewood That is not enough. Do you have jquery library like `node.js` installed in your system? or did you run `rails generate jquery:install`

Comment: @pavan Thanks for replying, no I don't think I do actually. I'll look into that.

Comment: @pavan I installed node.js and tried to run `rails generate jquery:install` but it could not find the generator.

Comment: @Gerry I've added the error log with `show` action.

Comment: Ok Installing node.js could be enough. Now try the link_to for delete and check if its working or not

Comment: @pavan I tried it but the show error returned.

Answer (score 1):

So it fixed the issue by looing into the application.html.rb file.

I switched:

```
%= stylesheet_link_tag :default, media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag :default %>
```

to:

```
%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

And everything worked.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the item is being correctly deleted? If it's not being deleted then:
I think you need a "form" and not a link_to.

link_to creates an `<a>` tag and if I'm not mistaken won't allow you to correctly do a "delete".

use: `form_for @YOUROBJECT, method: :delete do |f|`

That's why it's saying it doesn't find the "show" action on the controller, because the path for `todo_list_todo_item_path` without the delete method is the path for "show".

Another way would be with an Ajax request.

## If it's being correctly deleted:

You're missing an **action** in the controller and a **corresponding view for the correct controller**. Double-check since they're nested resources, you might be placing the show view on the wrong place.

Comment: On the tutorial I'm following (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fd1Vn-Wvy2w&list=PL23ZvcdS3XPLNdRYB_QyomQsShx59tpc-&index=6) a link_to is used to delete a todo_item.

Comment: Also, the item is not being deleted.

Comment: Please past the output from the terminal/server when you hit "delete".

Comment: @michael-nussbaumer I've added that now to my post.

Comment: @haletothewood indeed it seems you'll need first to figure out why your application.js / jquery isn't being loaded as suggested by nmeylan. The other way around would be to use a form instead of a link_to.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `application.js` file is not loaded.

`<%= link_to 'Delete', todo_list_todo_item_path(@todo_list, todo_item.id), 
method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>` Is the correct way to remove a record (if the route is correct)

Are you sure `application.js` is loaded?

the `method: :delete` is hooked by jquery_ujs to transform your link into an ajax link that will send an `http DELETE`. 
So if application.js is not loaded correctly, your link will behave like a `http GET` link to show action.

Comment: I have checked and the application.js file is there in app\assests\javascripts and both `//= require jquery` and `//= require jquery_ujs` are in there. I'm not sure what else I can do?